# Sending an HTTP request using PHP on Bluemix

Tags: php, httprequest, ibm-cloud

I have a project on www.bluemix.net that uses PHP. I try to send an HTTP request as shown in the code below, but I never reach the {echo "b";} command. I think that the HTTP request is not enabled, by default, when PHP is used on Bluemix.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

echo "a";
$request = new HttpRequest();    // I never pass this line
echo "b";
$request->setUrl('https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize');
$request->setMethod(HTTP_METH_POST);

?>
```

Has anyone used Bluemix this way and had the same issue with using an HTTP request?

Hint:
The project structure looks as follows:
[image]

Comment: They probably disable external HTTP requests for security purposes

Comment: You likely need to deploy this app to your runtime for it to execute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SOLVED] The issue is solved now, all I needed was to download the application to my computer, and install [composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md) locally, followed by pushing the whole thing to bluemix.

I believe that is not the best way, because I prefer to code directly on the cloud. Whatsoever, I'll summarize the steps that can be used to run HttpRequest with IBM bluemix:

1. Get a user name and password for [www.bluemix.net](http://www.bluemix.net)
2. Create a space, and an application (by command line or by user interface)
3. Install composer as described in the documentation [here](https://getcomposer.org/download/)
4. Go local to your computer, inside your application folder, modify the file ***composer.json*** to include any http package. For me, I used php-curl, so the file looks like

   `{`

   ```
       "require": {
           "php-curl-class/php-curl-class":"*"
       }
      "minimum-stability": "dev"
   ```

   `}`
5. Install the package using composer locally

   `php composer.phar install`

> Now, everything is ready we should push the whole application back to
>   bluemix:

1. Login to blue mix using username and password

   `bluemix login`
2. connect to IBM blue mix

   `bluemix api https://api.ng.bluemix.net`
3. Push the application, where  matches your application name

   `cf push <app_name>`

Answer (score 1):

The [HttpRequest module](https://pear.php.net/package/HTTP2) is an optional PEAR package. This won't be included by default in your PHP environment. Looking at this [thread](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack/issues/39), there a number of ways to get optional modules installed.

The simplest is to use Composer.

> You can use Composer to install them. Often times Pear modules are
>   also listed in the Composer repositories, so you can install them
>   directly with Composer instead. If not, you can also use Composer to
>   install Pear modules, which will pull them from the Pear repo.

PHP buildpack [documentation](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack/blob/master/docs/config.md#composer) has details about configuring Composer with your application.

Comment: Thanks for illustration. I agree with you that the easiest way to add HttpRequest module on bluemix is to use composer. As you can see in the attached image, the file composer.json is already in my project, so I think composer is installed by default. I modified composer.json as follows: 
{
    "require": {
        "comodojo/httprequest ": "1.2.*"
    }
}
This will add the HttpRequest module. Only one last step remains, I need to run "php composer.phar install". Do you know how to run this shell command directly on bluemix? Thanks